# How to automatically call a method when creating a case class

Tags: scala, logging, playframework

I am adding logging into my Play application, and in order to avoid cumbersome and repeated code I have created a case class with a formatting function inside in order to clean up my logs:

```
final case class LogMessage(keyValuePairs: (String, String)*) {
  def jsonify: String =
    s"""{${keyValuePairs map { case (key, value) => s""""$key":"$value"""" } mkString "," }}"""
}
```

Currently, in order to call this method I have to do something like:

```
Logger.info(LogMessage(("message", s"here is my message")).jsonify)
// jsonify prints:
// {"message":"here is my message"}
```

This runs fine, but I don't like how I need to write `.jsonify` after every time I make a new case class. Is there a way to make this method automatically called on creating a `LogMessage` case class so I don't have `jsonify` written all over my code? I have read about implicit methods but simply changing the method to `implicit def jsonify = ...` doesn't do anything.

Comment: Can you not just have a simple function that takes the list of pairs and returns a json representaiton of type string? I am not sure why you need a case class, unless you are simplifying it to post the question.

Comment: It has been simplified. Originally, it was just a function (`def LogMessage(keyValuePairs: (String, String)*): String = s".....`) and not a case class, but I've since been given some extra requirements to give more functionality to `LogMessage` and have made it into a case class. I'm probably making life more difficult for myself than I need to, but I'm now curious if there's a way to solve my issue as it's a problem I've never had to tackle before and could be useful in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be solved by overriding `toString` method of `LogMessage`, but there is also a better option.

Since actually there is no need to use instances of `LogMessage`, we can implement an `object` with its `apply()` method, which will serve as converter from tuples to the jsonified String:

```
object JsonifiedMessage {

  def apply(keyValuePairs: (String, Any)*): String = {
    val jsonified = keyValuePairs.map { case (key, value) => s""""$key":"$value"""" }.mkString(",")
    s"{${jsonified}}"
  }

}
```

Can be used as:

```
Logger.info(JsonifiedMessage(("a", 1), ("b", 2)))
```

Comment: I get a compilation error: `type mismatch; found: JsonifiedMessage required: String` ([see here](https://i.imgur.com/q3GqYuP.png))

Comment: Updated the answer with another approach to solve it.

Comment: That's exactly what I need, brilliant! Thanks :)